# Is there a SQL pattern to follow for historical tables that expire old records when new records come in?

Tags: sql, mysql, google-bigquery

| id | ... | effect_date | expire_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | 2023-10-23 | 9999-12-31 |
| 1 | ... | 2023-10-15 | 2023-10-22 |
| 1 | ... | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-14 |
| 1 | ... | 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-09 |

I have a history table that has an id, bunch of data columns, an effect_date and an expire_date.  When I ingest new data to this table, say I get a new row where id=1, I would set that row to have expire_date = `9999-12-31` and I would need to update the previous row to have an expire date of the latest effect_date - 1.  But I would like to do this check for all rows though and not assume they have the proper expire_dates.

I bet this is an established pattern, but I can't find the name of it, I'm sure i'm just googling the wrong stuff. Been trying to put together some SQL for this but it is very inefficient and I bet this is a very common solution that has tons of examples for it. Just looking for a pattern / examples I can follow that has a good implementation for this in SQL.

Comment: You could do it with just one date column `effect_date` - you can always deduce `expire_date` from the row with the next `effect_date` (if there is one)

Comment: You are possibly looking for [Type 2 Slowly Changing Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row)

Comment: You are correct this is an established pattern, Filburt link covers it well. To this point though "But I would like to do this check for all rows though and not assume they have the proper expire_dates." I always have a few boilerplate checks in place post-load. 1.) All expired records records have an associated record effective 1 second (or whatever interval) later i.e. your date chain is densely linked. 2.) Effective intervals never overlap for a given id, i.e. at any point in time you have 1 and only 1 effective record for an id. 3.) You have one and only one non-expired record per id.